# compile soft without cmake or how to install cmake without libcurl4

Tags: compiling, cmake

I want to compile **Dino** jabber client (https://dino.im/#download), but I can't because I have no cmake.

```
$ ./configure 
-!- CMake required.
```

I tried to install cmake, but I have some conflict with libcur3 and libcurl4:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cmake-data libcurl4 libjsoncpp1 librhash0 libuv1
Suggested packages:
  cmake-doc ninja-build
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcurl3 viber virtualbox-5.2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cmake cmake-data libcurl4 libjsoncpp1 librhash0 libuv1
```

But I don't want to remove viber, virtualbox!! :)

Is there some way to compile this software? 
Or may I install cmake with libcurl3... I don't know the right solution.

> Description:  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would be very useful if you provide download link for "Dine jabber client".

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry, there was a mistake, it's `Dino` - https://dino.im/#download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I have no idea how to compile in case of missed `cmake`, but we can install [Dino packages](https://github.com/dino/dino/wiki/Distribution-Packages)

- from [OBS for Debian 9](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=network:messaging:xmpp:dino&package=dino) (**preferable** as it is repository - you will get updates automatically):

  ```
  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/network:messaging:xmpp:dino.list
  deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/xmpp:/dino/Debian_9.0/ /
  EOF
  wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:messaging:xmpp:dino/Debian_9.0/Release.key -O Release.key
  sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install dino
  ```

  and launch it with `dino`.
- from [Debian experimental repository](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dino-im):

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dino-im/dino-im_0.0.git20180603-1_amd64.deb
  wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dino-im/dino-im-common_0.0.git20180603-1_all.deb
  sudo apt-get install ./dino-im*.deb
  ```

  and launch it with `dino-im`.